# canvas show part of hovered area as zoomed in square preview box

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a simple application i am working on, that allow you to load a photo into canvas, then i wanted to implement something like google inspector tool that as you are hovering any part of that photo inside of canvas it is giving you a zoomed preview of small region of the photo. For example `100x100` pixel square that allows you to see zoomed in part of photo. But unfortunately i have no idea how to start with this. The current code:

```
// Source Logic
var source_cvs = document.querySelector('.source'),
    source_ctx = source_cvs.getContext('2d'),
    source_w = source_cvs.width = 600,
    source_h = source_cvs.height = 400,
    img = new Image;

img.src = 'https://www.thecarpeople.co.uk/umbraco-media/Entry_492/c10a8f69-95b7-41ab-b341-73f1dd0fe6b2.jpg';

img.onload = function() {
    source_ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};

source_cvs.onmousemove = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;

    preview_render(x, y);
};

// Preview Logic
var preview_cvs = document.querySelector('.preview'),
    preview_ctx = preview_cvs.getContext('2d'),
    preview_w = preview_cvs.width = 100,
    preview_h = preview_cvs.height = 100,
    preview_render = function(x, y) {
        preview_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, preview_w, preview_h);
        preview_ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    };
```

Demo: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/8kxpzzk8/1/)

**EDIT: --------**

I have updated my code so it actually does what i need, it is displaying extra square properly, i am just having issues how to properly zoom the image and center it properly so it shows:

- -50px on the left from cursor
- -50px on the right from cursor
- -50px on the top from cursor
- -50px on the bottom from cursor

Just center image so cursor points in the middle.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that you are showing full image on hover while i need full image at all times and just zoom in the full image, more something like this: https://codepen.io/techslides/pen/zowLd just not exactly this one, as functionality go, something identical to google inspector tool

Comment: Try using [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com) rather than re inventing the wheel

Comment: noone is saying about reinventing the wheel, i also dont need heavy library just to draw extra square with zoomed part of image, just someone experienced with canvas coding to help out make it happen. What i need is just function that draws extra square that is 50 x 50px and has zoomed part of image cuted from original canvas where user is atm hovering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace clientX and clientY with offsetX and offsetY:

```
...
  var x = e.offsetX-7,
    y = e.offsetY-5;
...
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/580faho9/)